# How to compute the grand sum of a matrix?

Tags: r, pseudocode

I have a matrix of size 4 x 10. I want to compute the sum all possible entries of the sum. In other words, if you have a 2 x 2 matrix

```
2 3
4 1
```

then there are 2^2 sums (2 + 3, 2 + 1) and (4 + 3, and 4 + 1). Similarly, if you have a 2 x 3 matrix, there would be 2^3 = 8 total sums. Duplicates are allowed. Since my matrix is a 4 x 10, this has 1,048,576 total sums.

How exactly do I compute this in R? Pseudocode is also fine since I am fairly sure I can translate into R. But specialized R packages/functions would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
m <- matrix(c(2,3,4,1), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
apply(expand.grid(m[,2],m[,1]),1,sum)
[1] 5 3 7 5
```

Comment: This was a very nice solution. I had to add `m[, 3], m[, 4] ... ` to the `expand.grid` but takes about 6 seconds to work it out!

Answer (score 7):

A terse way to achieve this for a matrix with any number of columns would be with:

```
rowSums(expand.grid(as.data.frame(m)))
```

`as.data.frame(m)` converts your matrix to a data.frame, which means it can be directly passed to the `expand.grid` function, which will operate on each column. `rowSums` efficiently computes the row sums of the result, which will result in significant efficiency gains compared to using `apply` with function `sum`:

```
m <- matrix(1:40, nrow=4)
system.time(apply(expand.grid(m[,1],m[,2],m[,3],m[,4],m[,5],m[,6],m[,7],m[,8],m[,9],m[,10]),1,sum))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.866   0.108   4.971 
system.time(rowSums(expand.grid(as.data.frame(m))))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.141   0.030   0.171
```

**Edit:** As suggested by @Roland, this is not particularly memory efficient because it takes the full cross product of the columns before performing any additions. A harder to read but more memory efficient version would be:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) rowSums(expand.grid(x, y)), as.data.frame(m))
```